Compressing a string to a fixed length
I need to achieve string compression to a certain length.
The input is a string consisting of 3 to 16 characters, which can include the English alphabet in lowercase, digits (0-9), and underlines (or regex: ^[a-z0-9_]{3,16}$).
The English alphabet in any case, digits, underlines, brackets, and various other UTF-8 characters can be used to compress the original string. It must be possible to the reverse process: from the compressed string to the original string.
In my case, the specific length of the compressed string is 6. However, I do not know if it is possible to compress a 16-character string into a "6-character code". If this is not possible, then I suggest increasing it to 7-8 characters.
Example:
input: bestnickname
output: D_1(oP
I've been trying to find various algorithms to solve this problem, but I haven't found one.

You have 37 possible characters, so 6 bits each, 6*16=96, 96/8=12. You need 12 bytes. Unless there is something more you can assume about the strings.

@teapot418 Each char is 2 bytes, so this is very much doable in 6 characters.

@teapot418 You can easily do 21 bits per 4 characters, so 11 bytes per 16 characters is enough. Not that it saves you Java chars which are 2 bytes each...

a "6-character code" 6 chars or 6 Unicode code points? There’s a difference.

@Anonymous  6 chars

So 6 times 16 bits or 12 bytes in total, as others have mentioned. Thanks for being clear.

With nothing (much) known about the input strings, I'd call this recoding rather than compression. There is no such thing as a UTF-8 character. There are unicode characters, and three standardised encodings including UTF-8.

If, instead of UTF-8 (as specified in the question), the OP really wants to encode into UTF-16, which is how characters are encoded in Java (since the type char is referenced in the comments and the question is tagged "Java"), then indeed the specified 3 to 16 symbols where each symbol takes one of 37 values can be encoded into six 16-bit values constrained to valid UTF-16, with no surrogate values required, i.e. the old UCS-2. In fact, only 14 bits need to be encoded into each UTF-16 character, so a subset of characters can be chosen to be more readable.
To implement the encoder, first choose 16,384 Unicode characters within the valid code points 0x0000 to 0xffff (which excludes 0xd800 to 0xdfff) to permit in the encoded form. Make a map of 0..16383 to your chosen Unicode characters. Then assign an integer to each 3 to 16 37-value sequence. The calculation can be done using the BigInteger class. This result is an 84-bit integer. Break the 84-bit integer into six 14-bit pieces (fits perfectly!), and write the corresponding code point for each of the 14-bit pieces from your map.
Here is pseudo-code to compute the integer corresponding to a sequence:
    // len is in 3..16, seq[i] is in 0..36
    bigint base = 0;
    bigint offset = 37 * 37;
    for (int i = 3; i < len; i++) {
        offset *= 37;
        base += offset;
    }
    offset = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
        offset = 37 * offset + seq[i];
    return base + offset;

Where you would need to use the BigInteger methods for the arithmetic operations.

Requiring the result to be valid UTF-8 and minimizing the number of bytes (not Unicode characters) is an interesting problem. Not all byte sequences are valid UTF-8.
Even calculating the capacity of a UTF-8 stream is non-trivial. If I want to know how many four-byte sequences are valid and complete UTF-8, I need to consider all combinations of the number of bytes in each character that add up to four bytes: 1-1-1-1, 1-1-2, 1-2-1, 2-1-1, 2-2, 1-3, 3-1, and 4.
The number of valid UTF-8 characters of lengths 1, 2, 3, and 4 bytes are 27, 211-27, 216-212, and 220. Applying those to the combinations and summing gives that there are 383,270,912 valid and complete UTF-8 sequences that are four bytes in length. That represents about 28.5 bits, out of the 32-bits occupied, giving an 89% usage of the 32 bits.
The question asked for a fixed length, so we sum the number of possible 3 to 16 symbol sequences, where there are 37 symbols. That sum is 12,680,220,578,500,976,539,002,674. As noted elsewhere here, in a binary coding that would take 83.4 bits. For a fixed number of bytes, eleven would be required.
We repeat the process above to count valid UTF-8 sequences for 5, 6, etc. bytes, until we can cover the total number of 3 to 16 37-value symbols. It turns out that we need a 12-byte valid UTF-8 sequence for that. There are 73,122,690,434,759,781,773,213,696 possible such sequences, representing a capacity of 85.9 bits. Interestingly the usage is not much less for longer UTF-8 sequences, 85.9% for 12 bytes.
The answer to the question is that the minimum-length valid UTF-8 sequence required to represent 3 to 16 37-value symbols is 12 bytes.
To implement the encoding and decoding, the counting would be used to assign an integer to each 12-byte UTF-8 sequence. Similarly, an integer would be assigned to each 3 to 16 37-value sequence. That integer determines which 12-byte UTF-8 sequence it encodes to, and decoding gives the integer identification of the original symbol sequence.

You have roughly 1.3e25 possible combinations, meaning that you need 84 bits to encode that number of combinations. You'd need to do modulo-37 arithmetics and some tricks for the length information to squeeze the encoding into these 84 bits.
The main question is how big a subset of the Unicode characters you are willing to accept in the encoded string. Unrestricted, one unicode character can easily represent 17 bits, so 5 Unicode characters will be enough, as they will give you 85 bits.
But "The English alphabet in any case, numbers, underlines, brackets, and other various utf8 characters can be used to compress the original string" implies that unrestricted Unicode is not what you want.
So, the number of different characters allowed in the encoding, raised to the power of the desired encoded-string length, must be more than 1.3e25 to make the encoding possible.
So, count the different characters you want to allow in the encoded string, and calculate yourself. E.g. to achieve an 8-character encoding length, you'll need at least an alphabet of 1375 allowed characters.

So, let's say I agree to an encoding length of 8 characters. An alphabet of 1375 characters is not a particular problem. But I still don't understand how to implement all this, I would like to get a ready-made solution...

@user22150393 Sorry, I'm not available as a freelance developer.

I strongly suspect that "unicode characters" are in reality UTF-16 code units a k.a. Java char s.

Algorithms are described in various places. Sorry that I don’t have a pointer at hand.
